# How i make line graph on android device?

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I am using Titanium SDK. and I want to add line graph facility in my app.
my app is both device compatible (android and iphone). for line chart i am using google graph api. (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart). but is working with only iphone not with android.
with iphone working very good.
but, not working with android.
error message is : [Result of expression 'c[0]'[null] is not an object. ]
how i remove this issues
I am using this code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Month'); // Implicit domain label col.
            data.addColumn('number', 'Sales'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
            data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'}); // annotation role col.
            data.addRows([
                ['April',1000,    'A'],
                ['May',  1170,   'B'],
                ['June',  660,   'C'],
                ['July', 1030,  'c']
            ]);
            var options = {
              title: 'Company Performance'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you put this in a WebView? On Android a WebView with local resources is usually not able to load remote resources. You should check if the `google` object is available. If this is ok you should check the entire page within android's own web browser outside your app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your Revert. I 
got the solution. after expend some time. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working for my side.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
                width: 400, height: 400, annotationColumns:[{column:2, size:15, type:'flag', priority:'high'},], title: ''
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks to all.